# Getting UnparsedFlagAccessError when trying to import glog in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, glog, gflags

I am trying to use glog in my python code and when I am trying to import, it throws the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glog.py:171: RuntimeWarning: 
Trying to access flag verbosity before flags were parsed. This will raise 
an exception in the future. 
setLevel(FLAGS.verbosity)
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glog.py", line 171, in 
<module>
setLevel(FLAGS.verbosity)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gflags/flagvalues.py", line 
390, in __getattr__
traceback.print_stack()
E0602 09:45:07.674463 4695 flagvalues.py:399] Trying to access flag 
verbosity before flags were parsed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gflags/flagvalues.py", line 
391, in __getattr__
raise exceptions.UnparsedFlagAccessError(error_message)
UnparsedFlagAccessError: Trying to access flag verbosity before
flags were parsed.
```

My code is as follows.

```
import gflags 
import glog as log
```

I have searched online but haven't got any information about the python version of glog. I think this error has to do something with gflags and glog together. Can anyone please explain what is going wrong ?

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm not overly familiar with Python yet, but am wondering whether this a version conflict issue in glog. The examples for glog are quite old, and some of the class methods are throwing not found errors.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. After checking the code, it seems some kind of bug of glog.

When `import glog` is intercepted, it assumes `gflags.GFLAGS` has been initiated, and tries to read `gflags.GFLAGS.verbosity`, which actually is not guaranteed to be initialized in most cases.

For example, the following code will throw exception:

```
import gflags
import glog
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gflags.FLAGS(sys.argv)
    # do something.
```

Since when `import glog` is intercepted, it reads `FLAGS.vebosity`, but since `glfags.FLAGS(sys.argv)` is not executed yet, reading from `FLAGS` will fail.

So we have to make sure `import gflags` intercepted after `GFLAGS` being initialized, the only solution I could think of is putting `import glog` in another file instead of the main py script.

For example, in main script:

```
import gflags
import sys
# DON'T IMPORT ANYTHING that evolves of 'glog' 

FLAGS = gflags.FLAGS

if __name__ == "__main__":
    argv = FLAGS(sys.argv)
    # import any modle that uses 'glog'
    import your_other_module
    your_other_module.do_something()
```